# Android: How to separate different users in the firebase and restrict them in login?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two types of users--client and event member-- i saved their name, email, password, etc. to a firebase database. How will I restrict a client's email that he can't login in the event member activity; and how can I also restrict an event member's email that he can't login in the client activity? Please help me. Thank you!

Below image shows my firebase structure:
[My Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uX11i.jpg)

Comment: Add a new column that holds the member type then go from there

Comment: Add boolean which indicated whether your user is an event member or not. Then you can check it everytime you need.

Comment: @HonorLT:  Do I still need to use the Firebaseauth? And can you show me some code inidicating whether the user is an event member or not? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you still need FirebaseAuth. When user enters his/her credentials you retrieve this boolean (lets call it isEventMember) and check if it's true. If it is, you can open another activity. If it is not, you can inform user that he/she doesn't have access to it (probably show Toast message or something like that)

Answer (score 1):

You got 2 type of users but as I can see you save the exact information to client and event users. So first of all, you can make only one firebase structure for both user and just add a boolean variable CLIENT that indicates if a user is a client or event member. And to answer your other question you add another boolean variable MEMBER that indicates if a user can login to event or client activity. So here is my firebase model!!

```
users
-KrvzqA4GnTsomTzRHtT
    client: false
    birthday: "23/2/1986"
    country: "Philippines"
    emailAdd: "client's email"
    fname: "Steph"
    lname:"Diaz"
    mobileNum:"Client's mobile"
    password:"password"
    member: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one more value into your firebase user database which is your `"member_type"`. 
`"member_type" : "true"` if your member is client otherwise save it as a value `"member_type" : "false"`.

Then in your application after user logged in to your application retrieve that particular user's information and check if that user's `"member_type"` is client or event that is true or false?
If `"member_type"` is client then allow access to clientactivity otherwise allow access to EventActivity.

You database model would look something like this:

```
client
    -KrvzqA4GnTsomTzRHtT
        birthday: "23/2/1986"
        country: "Philippines"
        emailAdd: "client's email"
        fname: "Steph"
        lname:"Diaz"
        mobileNum:"Client's mobile"
        password:"password"
        member_type: true
eventMember
    -Ks-RHCoq0bUWJySDvCF
         birthday: "21/8/1992"
         country: "American Samoa"
         emailAdd: "eventmember's email"
         fname: "Patricia"
         lname:"Ortega"
         mobileNum:"eventmember's mobile"
         password:"password"
         member_type: false
```

You can also differentiate member_type either by boolean value or by integer or any other datatype you found useful.